# iPhone Accelerometer and landscape mode issue

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, landscape

I am calling a function in Accelerometer delegate method like this

This is in ViewControllerX.m

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
   [self methodX];
}
```

i am also calling another function in interface method like this

This method is in ViewControllerY

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

  [object methodY];
  //Here "object" is ViewControllerX.m 's Object,

}
```

The problem is, when i shake my iPhone

methodY is calling instead of, methodX.

can any one tell me how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

should simply return a BOOL value indicating whether or not the interfaceOrientation is supported or not.  From the UIViewController documentation:

> Your implementation of this method
>   should simply return YES or NO based
>   on the value in the
>   interfaceOrientation parameter. Do not
>   attempt to get the value of the
>   interfaceOrientation property or check
>   the orientation value reported by the
>   UIDevice class. Your view controller
>   is either capable of supporting a
>   given orientation or it is not.

In my experience, it is *not* a good idea to any extensive processing inside this method.